# How to fine tune sentence-transformers to understand the semantic similarity

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I am using BERT model for context search in the Italian language but it does not understand the contextual meaning of the sentence and returns the wrong result.

in the below example code when I compare "milk with chocolate flavor" with two other types of milk and one chocolate so it returns high similarity with chocolate. it should return high similarity with other kinds of milk.

can anyone suggest to me how to fine tune sentence-transformers so that it can understand the semantic meaning of the text and return similarity according to it?

**Code :**

```
!python -m spacy download it_core_news_lg
!pip install sentence-transformers


import scipy
import numpy as np
from sentence_transformers import models, SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('distiluse-base-multilingual-cased') # workes with Arabic, Chinese, Dutch, English, French, German, Italian, Korean, Polish, Portuguese, Russian, Spanish, Turkish

corpus = [
          "Alpro, Cioccolato bevanda a base di soia 1 ltr", #Alpro, Chocolate soy drink 1 ltr(soya milk)
          "Milka  cioccolato al latte 100 g", #Milka milk chocolate 100 g
          "Danone, HiPRO 25g Proteine gusto cioccolato 330 ml", #Danone, HiPRO 25g Protein chocolate flavor 330 ml(milk with chocolate flabor)
         ]
corpus_embeddings = model.encode(corpus)


queries = [
            'latte al cioccolato', #milk with chocolate flavor,
          ]
query_embeddings = model.encode(queries)


# Calculate Cosine similarity of query against each sentence i
closest_n = 10
for query, query_embedding in zip(queries, query_embeddings):
    distances = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist([query_embedding], corpus_embeddings, "cosine")[0]

    results = zip(range(len(distances)), distances)
    results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1])

    print("\n======================\n")
    print("Query:", query)
    print("\nTop 10 most similar sentences in corpus:")

    for idx, distance in results[0:closest_n]:
        print(corpus[idx].strip(), "(Score: %.4f)" % (1-distance))
```

**Output :**

```
======================

Query: latte al cioccolato

Top 10 most similar sentences in corpus:
Milka  cioccolato al latte 100 g (Score: 0.7714)
Alpro, Cioccolato bevanda a base di soia 1 ltr (Score: 0.5586)
Danone, HiPRO 25g Proteine gusto cioccolato 330 ml (Score: 0.4569)
```